# Mailer error missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, actionmailer

Hello,

I have problem with **ActionMailer**, when I try to execute action:

```
rake send_email
```

I get a error:

```
    rake aborted!
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template user_mailer/mailer with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "user_mailer"
```

Here's my:

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def mailer(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Test')
  end

end
```

**views/user_mailer/mailer.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Sample mail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views/user_mailer/mailer.text.erb**

```
Sample mail.
```

**lib/tasks/emails_task.rake**

```
desc 'send email'
task send_email: :environment do
  UserMailer.mailer(User.last).deliver!
end
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
# I recommend using this line to show error
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener

# config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
# config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
 :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}

# Send email in development mode?
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I searched for the solution on stackoverflow and I tried many of the answers for the similar problem but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

I found solution, when I add body to mailer method like:

```
def mailer(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Test', body: 'something')
end
```

Then it does work but I would like to have a body in separate files and make it more complex with user name and other things.

If someone have a idea how to solve this problem then I would be very thankful :)

Comment: I have found the same issue, and your fix works (though I still am getting a failure occasionally now.) Interestingly, this only happens in my production environment. Development works just fine. I'm still trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I also have the same issue! Just started a bounty :-)

Comment: Do you use whenever to run this? Try to run the command like this `RAILS_ENV=production rake send_email`

Comment: Have you checked this http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3 it is like you want i guess

Comment: I found a solution to this problem. I had not english character in one of the folders and because of that I had this problem. When I changed folder name to something else, the problem has been resolved.

Comment: I think `erb` handler is not avaiable, could you post the result of this command `ActionView::Template::Handlers.extensions`

Comment: Does the code `UserMailer.mailer(User.last).deliver!` work in the console?

Comment: @Kattaro what is use  of English character here? I have same issue when write body then it works but without it not. Can you give me suggestion for it.

Comment: The solution above (in the question) worked for me. That is, adding body: "something" to the mail method. I think my error was because my template was either wrongly formatted or wrongly named. I suspect adding body: "something" causes rails to not worry about looking for a template so my dodgy template is no longer an issue, even though it still exists

Answer (score 4):

Try adding layout

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  layout "mailer"

  def mailer(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Test')
 end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Restarting sidekiq solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Could you publish a minimalist Github repository reproducing your error?

You may try to generate your mailer in order to check you are not forgetting something:

`bundle exec rails generate mailer mailer_classname mailer_viewname`

In your case:

`bundle exec rails generate mailer user_mailer mailer`

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that Rails just isn't finding your newly created files. If you have the `spring` gem running, that could be the issue. (More on spring: https://github.com/rails/spring)

To setup terminal commands and stop running `spring`:

```
 $ bundle exec spring binstub --all
 $ bin/spring stop
```

I tried this, then re-running my app with `rails s`.  That didn't work so then try closing the terminal completely and rebooting your computer.  Run `rails s` and try testing with `rails c` in a second tab:

```
 mail = UserMailer.mailer(User.last)
```

That *finally* worked for me, hopefully it'll help some of you!

(Some of these steps may be redundant.)

Answer (score 3):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  layout "mailer"

  def mailer(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Test')
 end

end
```

Add a html layout under layout#

> mailer.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add text layout under layout #

> mailer.text.erb

```
<%= yield %>
```

Use preview to check your email based on your test framework.

Answer (score 2):

I renamed my method and it worked. Maybe the name of the method can't be mail or mailer...

Comment: Can you be specific? What method exactly?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini `def mailer(user)`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar issue. I had missed adding the gem 'haml-rails' in my Gemfile. Check if you are missing the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to delete mailer template file, in your case `views/user_mailer/mailer.html.erb` and to create it again. 
It seems that I created file with proper name but with some weird white space somewhere, and ActionMailer didn't recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

well, mine might be the silliest answer of all but mine work after deleting the template and recreating it with the same name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send html but tell rails not to place it inside a layout, do two things:

- instead of `html_body`, use `body` instead
- Also provide the `content_type: "text/html"` argument

```rb
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'info@example.com'

  def hello
    mail(
      subject: 'Hello from me',
      to: 'your.emailaddress@example.com',
      from: 'info@example.com',
      body: '<strong>Hello</strong> dear user...', # <--- use body instead of html_body
      content_type: "text/html"                    # <--- add this line too
      )
  end
end

TestMailer.hello.deliver_now
```