# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template signup_mailer/welcome_message with "mailer". Searched in: * "signup_mailer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Sidekiq to deliver my emails asynchronously but have had persistent errors about not being able to find the email template. It isn't consistent as it works from time to time (like when I'm testing). You can see that I have even tried specifying the path and name of the template.

The error I am receiving in Honeybadger is: `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template signup_mailer/welcome_message with "mailer". Searched in: * "signup_mailer"`

`app/mailers/signup_mailer.rb`

```
class SignupMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'hello@companycam.com'

  def welcome_message(company, user)
    @company = company
    @user = user
    @web_url = root_url
    mail(to: @company.email, subject: 'Welcome to CompanyCam', template_path: 'signup_mailer', template_name: 'welcome_message')
  end
end
```

You can see in the picture that there is in fact a view called `welcome_message.html.erb` and the text version as well located in `app/views/signup_mailer/`
[image]

Comment: change from `mail(to: @company.email, subject: 'Welcome to CompanyCam', template_path: 'signup_mailer', template_name: 'welcome_message') => to mail(to: @company.email, subject: 'Welcome to CompanyCam')`

Comment: That is what I had originally, but it still didn't work. That is why I tried manually setting the info.

Comment: Do any of the potential solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984400/mailer-error-missing-template) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried them all and it doesn't work. Side note, this is in Production

Comment: Did you try to restart Sidekiq? Maybe it's still working with an old version of your code? Please connect to your rails console and try to execute `SignupMailer.welcome_message(random_company, random_user)`

Comment: @LolWalid I have restarted Sidekiq, but I did just try executing that from the Rails Console and received the error. Any other idea?

Comment: I tried your code and I got the error because my file was named `welcome_message.html.erb.rb` but then I fixed it. Do you have gems like `haml` which may break the render of `erb file`?

Comment: @LolWalid nope no render modifications.

Comment: How did you solved it? I'm hitting a similar wall and wondering... in my case the name in the `template_name` is not being considered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out.

```
class SignupMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'hello@companycam.com' 
  layout "welcome_message"

  def welcome_message(company, user)
    @company = company
    @user = user
    @web_url = root_url
    mail(to: @company.email, subject: 'Welcome to CompanyCam')
  end
end
```